# Add default security configuration when dependency added (similar as spring security works)

Tags: spring-security

I'm trying to create a dependency jar to include common security configurations for several web apps.

What I'm trying to do is to declare my own authentication provider; login/logout url and intially authenticate any request, next to that I'd want to let the final developer just define their custom authenticated (or unauthenticated) URLS.

Is there some way to do this?

I think is similar to spring security when it's added into a spring boot app when the developer has not defined a configuration.

Here is how I've been trying to do it.

Common-security project

```java
@Configuration
public class MyCommonSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    SecUserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new CommonDetailsServiceImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new CommonPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Bean
    SecAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) throws Exception {
        CommonAuthenticationFilter filter = new CommonAuthenticationFilter();
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        filter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(new CommonAuthenticationFailureHandler());
        filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new CommonAuthenticationSuccessHandler());
        filter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/commonLogin");
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    ProviderManager authProvider() {
        CommonAuthenticationProvider provider = new CommonAuthenticationProvider(this.passwordEncoder(), this.userDetailsService());
        return new ProviderManager(new AuthenticationProvider[]{provider});
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .sessionManagement((session)-> session
                    .sessionFixation((sesFix) -> sesFix.changeSessionId())
            )
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                    .dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.ERROR).permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/commonLogin").permitAll()
            )
            .logout((logout)-> logout
                    .logoutUrl("/commonLogout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/view/welcome").permitAll()
            )
        ;
        return http.build();
    }


}
```

Implementator's spring boot web app.

```java
@Configuration
public class AppSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
            .shouldFilterAllDispatcherTypes(false)
            .dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.ERROR).permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/js/**", "/css/**", "/fonts/**", "/images/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        ;
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

When using browser to access /view/welcome page, I'm getting an 403 forbidden status code.

I'm trying to append requestMatchers to same SecurityFilterChain from different jars